# How do you call a specific value from inside a math function?

Tags: javascript, forms, math

In this code I add a number of values based on a form and subtract the lowest value which creates a new total. The code works great. What I would like to do is instead of only having the new total at the bottom, I would like 3. One that says the original Total without the subtraction, One with the value of the lowest price that I subtract, and then finally the actual new total. As of now it is only displaying the new total.

Example: There are 3 items a scarf for $5, a hat for $10, and a jacket for $20. I add all the values which equals $35, I then subtract the lowest value which is the scarf for $5 and get a new total of $30. I want to display this at the bottom.

Total: $35 
Discount: $-5 
New Total: $30

The function already figures out all these values, I just don't know how to call them from the function.

```
// All selected prices are stored on a array
var prices = [];

// A function to remove a item from an array
function remove(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    // We add or remove the price as necesary

if (checkbox.checked) {
    prices.push(amount);
} else {
    remove(prices, amount);
}

// We sum all the prices
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
    total += prices[i];

// We get the lower one
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);


if(min == Infinity) { min = 0; };

// And substract it
total -= min;

document.grad_enroll_form.total.value = total;
```

}

Comment: What happens if the user only selects one item? In that case the total price after disount will be 0...

Comment: That is actually fine with what I'm doing but I can see how that might be a problem for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some basic code for you that just writes out the values. I *still* do not agree with your looping for removing elements from an array.

```
<span id="value"></span>
```

```
var prices = [];

function remove(arr,itm){
    var indx = arr.indexOf(itm);
    if (indx !== -1){
        arr.splice(indx,1);
    }
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        prices.push(amount);
    } else {
        remove(prices, amount);
    }

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
        total += prices[i];

    var min = prices.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0];
    if(typeof min === 'undefined') min = 0;

    var withDiscount = total - min;
    var discountAmount = withDiscount - total;
    
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML = "Total: $"+total+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "Discount: $"+discountAmount+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "New total: $"+withDiscount+'<br>';
}
```

Run like this:

```
calculateSectedDues({checked:true},10);
calculateSectedDues({checked:true},20);
calculateSectedDues({checked:true},5);
```

Gives this output:

> Total: $35
> Discount: $-5
> New total: $30

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/k5MXP/)

---

## Using checkboxes

```
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,5)" name="Scarf"> <span>Scarf</span><label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,10)" name="Hat"> <span>Hat</span><label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,20)" name="Jacket"> <span>Jacket</span><label><br>

<span id="value">Total: $0<br>Discount: $0<br>New total: $0</span>
```

Comment: Sorry @DJDavid98. People kept submitting formatting changes and I just didn't think I was wording it correctly so I resubmitted it a couple different ways. I apologize for any confusing but I really appreciate you sticking it out. So where you are saying I run it. CalculateSelectedDues({checked:true},10); , I am going to list all the values or can I add those to my form like <input type="checkbox" onlick="javascript: calculateSectedDues({checked:true},10);"> ?

Comment: @colestrode Yep, had a little piece of code left at the bottom, try http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/k5MXP/4/

Comment: @DJDavid98, that works perfectly! Is there anyway of forcing the total, discount, and new total to always display even before the boxes are checked?

Comment: @DJDavid98 you are a machine! thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @DJDavid98 If i wanted to add something before Total, Discount, and New total and make it a set value, what would i do? say its Shipping: FREE

Comment: @Alfie_Fitz If you need further assistance with the code, please add me on skype: `guzsik.david`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what your HTML looks like, but something like this would work. It uses jQuery to grab all checkboxes that are checked and adds the values of those checkboxes to a total and keeps track of the minimum value. Then it returns all three values in a single object.

I'm assuming that the values of your checkboxes are the prices of the items, which may not be true. If not, the idea will still work, you'll just have to do more work to get the correct price.

```
function calculate() {
    var total = 0, 
        discount = 0
    ;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(discount === 0 || val < discount) {
            discount = val; // keep track of minimum
        }

        total += val;
    });

    //return all three values in one object
    return {
        total: total,
        discount: disount,
        discountedPrice: (total - discount)
    }
}
```